# COUNT or SUM(CASE) From single column in single column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm having a problem which I've been staring at for hours and can't seem to solve.
I have a table which reads as:

```
CALLS  
CALL_REF {PK}  
TIME  
CALLER_ID {FK}  
DETAIL  
TAKEN_BY {FK}  
ASSIGNED_TO {FK}  
STATUS
```

Example rows being:

```
1411 8/19/2014 1808 0093 "Detail" AB2 EB1 Closed  
1372 8/19/2014 1238 0096 "Detail" MM1 MW1 Open
```

What I need to do is count the amount of closed and open for a certain date and between a certain time creating an output of:

```
Date        Shift   Status  Calls  
19-AUG-14   early   Closed  47  
19-AUG-14   early   Open    1  
19-AUG-14   late    Closed  38
```

Shift is taken from another table.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT shifts.shift_date AS "Date", 
       shifts.shift_time AS "Time", 
       calls.status      AS "Status", 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN calls.status = 'Closed' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL 
           end)          AS "Open Calls", 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN calls.status = 'Open' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL 
           end)          AS "Closed Calls" 
FROM   calls 
       INNER JOIN shifts 
               ON shifts.shift_date = calls.call_date 
WHERE  calls.call_date = '19-AUG-14' 
       AND calls.call_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('08:00', 'HH24:MI') AND 
                                   TO_DATE('14:00', 'HH24:MI') 
        OR calls.call_date = '19-AUG-14' 
           AND calls.call_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('14:00', 'HH24:MI') AND 
                                       TO_DATE('20:00', 'HH24:MI') 
GROUP  BY shifts.shift_date, 
          shifts.shift_time, 
          calls.status 
ORDER  BY shifts.shift_time, 
          calls.status;
```

Which outputs:

```
Date       Time    Status   Open Calls  Closed Calls  
19-AUG-14   Early   Closed              85  
19-AUG-14   Early   Open        1  
19-AUG-14   Late    Closed              85  
19-AUG-14   Late    Open        1
```

Clearly this is wrong but I'm clueless as to how to combine the two and separate them between the two shift times.
Please help!

Here's the complete layout of the database if you need it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKGHU.png

[image]

Edit:
I'm now using || between the two sum statements which is moving them into the same column. The figures are still totals however. They need to be split between the early and late shifts.

```
SELECT SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE AS "Date", 
       SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME AS "Time", 
       CALLS.STATUS AS "Status",
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CALLS.STATUS = 'Closed' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL END) ||
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CALLS.STATUS = 'Open' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL END) AS "Calls" 
FROM CALLS 
INNER JOIN SHIFTS
        ON SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE = CALLS.CALL_DATE 
WHERE CALLS.CALL_DATE = '19-AUG-14' 
  AND (CALLS.CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('08:00','HH24:MI') 
  AND TO_DATE('14:00','HH24:MI') 
OR CALLS.CALL_DATE = '19-AUG-14' 
  AND CALLS.CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('14:00','HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('20:00','HH24:MI') 
)
GROUP BY SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE, 
         SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME, 
         CALLS.STATUS
ORDER BY SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME, 
         CALLS.STATUS;
```

Comment: TO_DATE('14:00', 'HH24:MI') gives you current year, current month, 1st day of the month 14:00. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the syntax may be incorrect as I am not familiar with Oracle but I think the query below should give you the desired results based on your original query.

```
SELECT
    Date
    , Shift
    , Status
    , COUNT(*) AS "Calls"

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE AS "Date"
            , CASE
                WHEN SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('08:00','HH24:MI')
                                           AND TO_DATE('14:00','HH24:MI')
                    THEN 'Early'
                ELSE 'Late'
            END AS "Shift"
            , CALLS.STATUS AS "Status"

        FROM
            CALLS
            INNER JOIN SHIFTS
                ON  CALLS.CALL_DATE = SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE

        WHERE
            CALLS.CALL_DATE = '19-AUG-14'
            AND CALLS.CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('08:00','HH24:MI')
                                    AND TO_DATE('20:00','HH24:MI')
    ) AS ShiftGroup

GROUP BY
    Date
    , Shift
    , Status
```

Comment: This is close but it's getting a lot of invalid identifiers in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty obvious (now that I'm looking at it again).  Your projection include Status:

```
   calls.status      AS "Status",
```

So you have to include Status in the group by clause, at that means your aggregations are summed for records with only that Status, and so one aggregation is null on each line.  I have a SQL Fiddle with a simplified version of your query.  [Check it out.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b82b/2)

The solution is to remove STATUS:

```
SELECT SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE AS "Date", 
       SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME AS "Time", 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CALLS.STATUS = 'Closed' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL END) as "Closed Calls",
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN CALLS.STATUS = 'Open' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL END) AS "Open Calls" 
FROM CALLS 
INNER JOIN SHIFTS
        ON SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE = CALLS.CALL_DATE 
WHERE CALLS.CALL_DATE = '19-AUG-14' 
  AND (CALLS.CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('08:00','HH24:MI') 
  AND TO_DATE('14:00','HH24:MI') 
OR CALLS.CALL_DATE = '19-AUG-14' 
  AND CALLS.CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('14:00','HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('20:00','HH24:MI') 
)
GROUP BY SHIFTS.SHIFT_DATE, 
         SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME
ORDER BY SHIFTS.SHIFT_TIME;
```

Comment: But that's not the case for aggregate functions, is it?